# Ошибка preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'f'

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Из-за чего может возникнуть ошибка - preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'f'
Сам код:

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('#' .  $filter_base["filter"] . '#i', $text_comment)) 
    {           
         //var_dump($filter["filter"]);
         $delete = $instagram->deleteMediaComment($media_id, $comment_id);  
     }
?>
```

паттерт это слово, $text_comment это весь текст комментария.

Answer (score 1):

А в $filter_base["filter"] не попадаются недопустимые символы, скажем '#'?? Пример:

```
$filter_base["filter"] = "[ds]#f[.]+"
```

В итоге вы ожидаете: #[ds]#f[.]+#i. Имеете: #[ds]#f, где f тот самый неизвестный модификатор

Comment: как правильно сформировать паттерн?

Comment: А что конкретно требуется матчить? Что вы передаете в $filter_base?

Comment: Например у нас есть комментарий вида - "Подпишись взаимно", а в $filter_base["filter"] у нас например слово "подпишись", так вот если он находит это слово в тексте, то условие срабатывает.

Comment: и вообще, почему не работает флаг i? Поиск регистрозависим, хотя i делает его регистронезависимым

Comment: @foozzi, предполагаю, что из-за несоответствия кодировок

Comment: У вас сайт случайно не UTF8 использует? Если да, то попробуйте добавить модификатор u